# Error publishing log file TFS2012

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have en problem with TFS2012 after i have install an Visual Studio 2012 on a Microsoft Server 2012. Im gettting this error:

```
Exception Message: TF270016: An error occurred publishing log files from 'D:\Builds\3_2\MES_Projects\PJDGatewayTester - Main\Sources\Src\LPS_CMData\PJDGatewayTest.log' to '\\Server\Drop\Build\PJDGatewayTester - Main\PJDGatewayTester - Main_.6\logs'. Details: Access to the path '\\server\Drop\Build\PJDGatewayTester - Main\PJDGatewayTester - Main_.6\logs' is denied. (type PublishLogFileException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Access to the path '\\server\Drop\Build\PJDGatewayTester - Main\PJDGatewayTester - Main_.6\logs' is denied. (type UnauthorizedAccessException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectory(String fullPath, String path, Object dirSecurityObj, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.FileSpec.CopyFile(String oldPath, String newPath, Boolean overwriteExisting)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.WindowsDropProvider.CopyDirectory(String sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.WindowsDropProvider.CopyDirectory(String sourceDirectory, String targetDirectory, String[] renameIfExists)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.PublishLogFile.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
 The workflow instance has been canceled. (Reason: The activity 'Try Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items' with ID 12211 threw or propagated an exception while being canceled.)
 An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Access to the path '\\server\Drop\Build\PJDGatewayTester - Main\PJDGatewayTester - Main_.6\Logs' is denied.
 An error occurred while copying diagnostic activity logs to the drop location. Details: Access to the path '\\server\Drop\Build\PJDGatewayTester - Main\PJDGatewayTester - Main_.6\Logs' is denied.
```

Comment: Whatever user/service account you're using to try and do whatever it is your're trying to do doesn't have read/write permissions to access the drops folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to give permissions for your build service account to the drop location.

Comment: Please add: Which permissions and how are they granted